# Why does an event with conditional is not being triggered?

Tags: arrays, events, collections, anylogic

I am trying to send a JavaClass from one agent to another. For this, I am first creating instances of that JavaClass in one event. That event runs at a rate of 1 per second in the simulation. The first event is populating an array. Upon the conditional that whenever that array has a value, my second event should trigger.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kkFc.png)

The problem is that first event is working fine but the second event triggers only for first few seconds of the model simulation time rather than for my customized 3000 seconds model simulation time unit.

I tried to check if the logics in any of the events is not workinf right. For that I debugged my code.

I found that the collections of offloading and unassignedTasks was never empty to trigger the first event so I fixed that by applying //unassignedTasks.clear() //Offloading.clear(); wherever it was required. This helped the first event to run 200 times instead of the 100 times it was running previously.

The offloading array was giving the expected results of being empty but unassignedTasks array was populated with 1 JavaClass till the end of simulation. This should have made the OffloadTask to be triggered. However, OffloadTask is not being triggered.

I can not understand what is hindering the second event from being triggered. Even though, the conditional is fulfilled. Any guidance or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please simplify this to the core problem, looks like the first 80% is irrelevant to your latest problem. Pls learn to focus on the root issue and make our lives easy 

Comment: Sorry for inconveniences. Kindly check now.

Comment: @Benjamin  Thank you for your guidance. I found the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The event with conditional was not being triggered again because events in AnyLogic occur only once if they are based upon conditions.
I found the details here: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/statecharts/events.html

Applying eventname.restart(); in the end of your event action solves this problem.

Comment: thx for sharing. Never use conditional events or transitions, unless you are _very_ advanced and understand the underlying mechanisms. They can deceivevery easily